# ループの途中でループ数を増やす方法はあるか

Tags: ruby

Rubyでプログラミングしています．
表題の通り，以下の`each`文のループ回数`num`を，`each`スコープ内で増やすことができますでしょうか．

ご教授宜しくお願いします．
以下，サンプルプログラムです．

```
num = 10
NumList = []
(0 ... num).each do |i|    

    if i == 5   # このifに入ったら大ループ数numを+1する
        NumList[-1] = 99
        #num += 1
    else
        NumList << i        
    end

end

p "NumList = #{NumList}"
```

現出力　："NumList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 99, 6, 7, 8, 9]"
期待出力："NumList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 99, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]"

Comment: Range の上限値を予め増やしておくという方法もあろうかと思います。https://paiza.io/projects/u3xxJwdbLqLFXcVZw3Nihg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

普通に`while`で書いたらいいのではないでしょうか。

```
num = 10
NumList = []
i = 0
while i < num
  if i == 5 # このifに入ったら大ループ数numを+1する
    NumList[-1] = 99
    num += 1
  else
    NumList << i
  end
  i += 1
end

p "NumList = #{NumList}"
```

Answer (score 3):

`Range.enum`だけでは無理なので、追加分を配列として連結すればどうでしょうか。

```rb
range = (0...num)
additional = []
[range, additional].lazy.flat_map{|enum| enum.lazy}.each do |i|
    if i == 5
        NumList[-1] = 99
        additional << 10
    else
        NumList << i
    end
end
```